# Process.GetProcessByName returns empty when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, process

I have this code:

```
foreach (var processToKill in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer.exe"))
{
    processToKill.Kill();
}
```

However, when I run it, processToKill always returns empty. explorer.exe is running:

[image]

This is on windows 8.1, but also occurs on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extension from the process name.

You can try using the following code for that:

```
     Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("explorer.exe"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no EXPLORER.EXE. There is an EXPLORER without the extension.

Just try with

```
foreach (var processToKill in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
{
    processToKill.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Is this true for all programs or just explorer?

Comment: Run this on LinqPAD and see by yourself **Process.GetProcesses().Select(x => x.ProcessName).OrderBy(x => x).Dump();**